# Exposing partial objects with nHibernate and Json.Net

Tags: c#, nhibernate, json.net, nancy

I am developing a REST API based on Nancy and nHibernate. Like in most REST API's I want to limit the amount of properties that I show when the resource is shown as part of a collection (/customers) compared to when it's shown as a resource (customers/1)

Obviously, I can hack something together where I map stuff back and forth, but I am looking for the most generic solution as possible. I see two strategies:

1. Modify the serialization - so load the full object from nHibernate
   but have a strategy for determining which properties to show. I have
   unsuccesfully tried to customize the serialization of JsonNet so
   that it respects if the object is cast to an interface (ie.
   ICustomerReference) or a base class ( so that the full 'Customer' inherits from
   the simpler 'CustomerReference' class)
2. Modify the data model and consequently the nHibernate model, so that it follows the latter idea
   mentioned above, where the full 'Customer' class inherits from the simpler 'CustomerReference' class. Also
   unsuccesful, as nHibernate will give me the full object, even though I ask it to load/get the 'CustomerReference' class.

Let me know, if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Do you have requirement to persiste customer reference back to the database? Or is it for display purposes only?

Comment: Obviously, I would be a nice feature, if a customer could be PUT while creating the order. But for now, absolutely no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve the second approach by creating a "Lite" version for every class you want to expose(as you called it - Reference).
In order not to fetch the full object from the table you should use NHibernate Projections.
One of the main uses of Projections is to help you to limit the full mapping to specific properties(You can do additional manipulation such as different aggregations). 
You can control the Projections dynamically, but it require to build some kind of mechanism to choose which property to fetch in each call.
Another major advantage of Projections is you can flatten the object. If the object is complex with collections and complex elements as property you can project almost anything to one flat object.

Comment: I was hoping to do it as natively as possible, so that querying would not be necessary. I will though accept that for a collection which by nature has multiple results is query. But can projections also be applied for a property? The second usage for a lite object would usually be a nested class that serves as a reference from a fully loaded object. Ie. a nested customer object on an order.

Answer (score 1):

This is a display only view, and for those most likely approach would be to use a DTO object (something like CustomerListRowDTO) and get it populated via a query (in case of NHibernate it would be something like HQL or a QueryOver)

This might prove to be useful if you want to also display something like number of order per client, which requires use of a subquery, and using of Entities to populate such table ends up with executing too many queries with lower performance.